# to change months to exact days?

Tags: iphone

i am using following code to get months correctly....it returns correct data..but it gives
2 months when i get from two dates...suppose if i give two dates like janauary to march,
it will give 2 months...how can i change to no of days exactly(included feb)...

```
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];


unsigned int unitFlags = NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

NSLog(@"Break down: %dmons", [breakdownInfo month]);
```

Answer (score 1):

By only specifying the `NSDayCalendarUnit` flag when creating the date components, you will get the number of days as result of `[breakdownInfo day]`.

Comment: it gives wrong out put...month returns 2.. but days return only 13 after i implemented your Way... t

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong then. If you only set the day unit, only the day field will contain a valid value. The other fields are just random so you can't use them. When I just set the day unit, comparing two days that are one month apart, I get for example 30 in the day field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSDateComponents`, but you can count days simply by taking the difference of each date's timeInterval.  `NSTimeInterval` is a floating point number that counts the number of seconds.

```
#define kSecondsInDay 86400

int numberOfDays = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1] / kSecondsInDay;
```